# Error when configuring GCC compiler in Eclipse

Tags: gcc, eclipse-cdt

We have our own GCC based compiler. We use eclipse in order to develop .c files using our compiler – after hitting the build button eclipse manages to run our ‘make’ file and the build operation **succeeds**. 
We’re trying to configure the eclipse project such that it will use this compiler in order to show the compilation errors as red underline marks during the code-writing stage.

In order to do so, we add the following configurations:

1. Project properties > C/C++ Build>Tool chain editor > current toolchain: “Cross GCC”, current builder: “CDT internal builder”
2. Project properties > C/C++ Build>Settings>Tool Settings>Cross Settings> - here I set the prefix and the path of my GCC compiler.
3. Project properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor include path, Macro etc. > providers > check: “CDT Cross Build Output Parser” and inside check “Allocate console in the console view”.

After doing that we get the following error in the console view:

> i486-elf-g++ -E -P -v -dD
>   C:/Users/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/spec.C
>   Cannot run program "i486-elf-g++": Launching failed Error: Program
>   "i486-elf-g++" not found in PATH

It looks like eclipse is trying to compile a file named “spec.C”, in the plugin directory. We tried to look for that file and we only found an auto-generated file called “spec.c” (lower case .c) that is empty.

Our compiler executable name is “i486-elf-gcc”.

What additional steps need to be done?

Note that running the make file using the “build” button completes without errors or warnings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the `spec.c`. It seems that the path of the `i486-elf-gcc` is not in the PATH variable. You can add the path the `PATH`-varaible in the "Environment" -tab